# Solving an equation that contains a logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the follwing equation:

$$y=\frac 1 4x^2 -\frac 1 2 \ln{x}$$

How can $x$ be expressed in terms of $y$?

Comment: This isn't possible in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: what is your question write it correctly

Comment: I was not satisfied with the formulation of the problem. My English is not very good, but I think  'express' is an appropriate term . If it not, please ´help tofind the right word.

Comment: This is decreasing from $0$ to $1$, then increasing, In general there will be two $x$ for every $y$.  And, as has already been observed, we cannot solve using elementary functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$y=\frac14 x^2-\frac12 \log x\tag 1$$

Multiplying $(1)$ by $-4$ yields

$$\begin{align}
-4y&=- x^2+2 \log x\\\\
&=-x^2+\log x^2 \tag 2\\\\
\end{align}$$

Now, exponentiating both sides of $(2)$ and multiplying by $-1$ reveals that

$$-e^{-4y}=-x^2e^{-x^2} \tag 3$$

from which we find that

$$x=\sqrt{-W(-e^{-4y})}$$

where $W(z)$ is the [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  Note we rejected negative values of $x$ since in $(1)$ we have $\log x$.

We must have $W\le 0$ and $-e^{-4y}\ge -e^{-1}\implies y\ge \frac14$.

Comment: You are too fast for the old man ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Well ... I might be close to you there ... and slow.  Plus 3 days out of surgery!!

Comment: I wish you a prompt recovery !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you!!  Forth surgery in a year and the second in 4 months.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, the solution of equation $$\frac 1 4x^2 -\frac 1 2 \ln{x}-y=0$$ cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

However, there are explicit solutions in terms of Lambert function. Chenging variable $x^2=t$, the equation write $$t-\log(t)-4y=0$$ and the solution is $$t=-W\left(-e^{-4 y}\right)$$

You must notice that $y'=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2 x}$ cancels at $x=1$ and, at this point $y=\frac 14$ and the second derivative is always positive. So, if $y<\frac 14$, there is no real root; if $y=\frac 14$, the only root is $x=1$ and if $y>\frac 14$, there are two real roots (one between $0$ and $1$, another larger than $1$).

Comment: Not so slow after all!